# How do I change x-axis values in a grouped lattice xyplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, lattice

I have following sample data in R.

```
d <- read.table(text = 
"Grp     Var    Col1  Col2    Col3
grp_1   8      46.8  50.0   50.6
grp_1   16     95.6  47.4   48.0
grp_1   24     45.1  45.6   46.4
grp_1   32     68.8  44.3   58.2
grp_1   40     44.6  52.2   44.3
grp_1   48     86.5  42.2   68.6
grp_2   40     63.2  95.6   63.0
grp_2   60     66.7  67.5   65.6
grp_2   80     69.6  70.7   67.9
grp_2   100    71.9  73.4   69.3
grp_2   120    73.8  75.7   48.0
grp_3   500    51.9  50.0   50.5
grp_3   1000   65.5  53.0   53.4
grp_3   5000   61.2  99.0   59.9
grp_3   10000  80.1  63.0   62.8
grp_3   30000  25.9  33.8   14.2
  ", header=T
)
```

The columns `Col1`, `Col2`, and `Col3`, for each group, need to be plotted against `Var.` Group 1 has 6 values each for Var, Col1 - Col3, While groups 2 and 3 have 5 values. I am using Lattice's `xyplot()` function to plot them in a grid. The code is below:

```
#Groups as factors
d$Grp <- factor(d$Grp, levels=c("grp_1","grp_2","grp_3"), order=TRUE)
#Plot the data
xyplot(
  Col1 + Col2 + Col3 ~ Var | Grp,
  data=d,
  superpose=T,
  as.table=TRUE,
  col=c("#cc0000","#008000", "#0073e6"),
  lwd=1.5, ylim = c(0,120),
  ylab = list(label=expression("My Values"), fontsize=15),
  xlab = list(label="Var",fontsize=15),
  key=list(
    text  = list(c("Col1", "Col2", "Col3")),
    lines = list( lwd=1.5, col=c("#cc0000","#008000", "#0073e6")),
    corner = c(1, 0),
    x = 0.90, 
    y = 0.17),
  par.settings = list(strip.background=list(col="white")),
  scales=list(cex=1.2),
  type=c("l","g")
)
```

The plot looks like this:

[image: Code output]

Clearly, the group 1 and 2 plotted values look messy because x-axis values are `500,1000,5000,10000,30000` instead of `8,16,24,32,40,48` and `40,60,80,100,120`. Is there any way to fix x-axis values for group 1 and 2 using `xyplot()` (preferably)? I am also open for other cool suggestions. The expected output could for example be like this:

[image: Desired output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the `scales` option with `relation="free"`, I get a plot similar to @Tjebo's above.. not 3 identical plots:

```
xyplot(
  Col1 + Col2 + Col3 ~ Var | Grp,
  data=d,
  superpose=T,
  as.table=TRUE,
  col=c("#cc0000","#008000", "#0073e6"),
  lwd=1.5, ylim = c(0,120),
  ylab = list(label=expression("My Values"), fontsize=15),
  xlab = list(label="Var",fontsize=15),
  key=list(
    text  = list(c("Col1", "Col2", "Col3")),
    lines = list( lwd=1.5, col=c("#cc0000","#008000", "#0073e6")),
    corner = c(1, 0),
    x = 0.90, 
    y = 0.17),
  par.settings = list(strip.background=list(col="white")),
  scales=list(cex=1.2,x=list(relation="free")),
  type=c("l","g")
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you cleverwolf :), exactly what I needed! The plots won't be identical, it was just for the illustration of the expected output.

Comment: Is it possible to give each plot a separate x-axis title? Please see my expected output. I tried `xlab = list(label=c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3"),fontsize=15)` but it changed the text at the bottom of the plot grid (means, replaced Var by Var1, Var2, Var3 at the bottom) and not the title of each plot.

Comment: it doesn't work because panel.xyplot doesn't take in individual axis labels.. hmm might have to define a manual panel.xyplot.. you give it a shot? I can take a look later

Comment: You are right, I was digging into https://www.stat.ubc.ca/~jenny/STAT545A/block10_latticeNittyGritty.html but couldn't manage to do so. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Because you have tagged it ggplot2 as well, here a ggplot2 solution.

I personally think that this is much easier than base plot, but I am incredibly biased.

```r
library(tidyverse)

d_long <- 
  d %>%
    pivot_longer(names_to = "key", values_to = 'value', contains("Col"))

ggplot(d_long, aes(Var, value, color = key)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(~Grp, scales = "free_x") +
  scale_color_manual(values =c("#cc0000","#008000", "#0073e6"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion, I keep my fingers crossed for some help on xyplot() :).

Answer (score 0):

The `plot.trellis` method allows one to plot `lattice` objects on a grid. By combining that with `update.trellis` method, one  can create a layout of arbitrary spacings.

I post this answer (a bit late) to highlight these options in `lattice`. My answer also starts in the spirit of the "tidyverse" by creating a long format for the data.

```
# first update the lattice parameters in 'tp'
    library(lattice)
    tp <- trellis.par.get() # retrieve all parameters
    tp$strip.background$col <- "white"
    tp$superpose.line$col <- c("#CC0000","#008000", "#0073E6")
    tp$superpose.line$lwd <- 1.5

# data from example already 'd' then convert with simple base functions
    myDat <- cbind(d[1:2], stack(d[3:5])) # new variables: "values" & "ind"

# create single plot object
    obj <- xyplot(values ~ Var | Grp, df, groups = ind, type = c("g", "l"),
        par.settings = tp, scales = list(x = list(relation = "free")),
        ylab = "My Values", xlab = "Place holder", as.table = TRUE)
```

The lattice object (`obj`) has the desired format but with only one x-axis label. It can simply be plotted by `obj` or `plot(obj)` in *almost* the desired form. However, since it actually is three lattice plots, they can extracted, updated, and plotted in a grid with the `update.trellis` and `plot.trellis` methods as shown here.

```
# axis labels and key 
    xlabs <- paste("My x-axis title", 1:3)
    myKey = list(corner = c(5, 0.5), points = FALSE, lines = TRUE)

# assemble final plot
    plot(update(o[1], xlab = xlabs[1]), split = c(1,1,2,2), more = TRUE)
    plot(update(o[2], xlab = xlabs[2]), split = c(2,1,2,2), more = TRUE)
    plot(update(o[3], xlab = xlabs[1], auto.key = myKey),
        split = c(1,2,2,2), more = FALSE)
```

[image: plot produced by update.trellis and plot.trellis]
By using `position` option instead of the `split` option, one can take finer control over the position of each plot.